How to fix double slash url in wordpress which contains 404 error
I'm encountering an issue with one of my WordPress URLs, which is resulting in a double slash URL and a redirect error. How can I rectify this so that it gets indexed in the search console and resolved ?
Example https://www.example.com/hindi-to-english-translation//1000
I have tried htaccess code to fix it

Anyone can resolve my problem about double slash url error
